# Does DynamoDB TTL work on pre-existing items?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, ttl

I have a DynamoDB table with a bunch of items in it.  I had configured the table to use the attribute "expiration" as the TTL attribute.  I then introduced a bug in my system where I saved all of the items with an attribute of "expiry" (doh!).

To solve this, I turned off TTL support on the table, then re-enabled it using the attribute "expiry".  There should have been an earth-shattering kaboom as all of the expired items went away.  There wasn't.  I waited 24 hours, just in case Dynamo needed to wake up and pay attention to my table.  No earth-shattering kaboom (sad martian...).

I'm now wondering if items in the table that were in place prior to enabling TTL on the correct attribute actually miss the TTL boat and will remain there until manually deleted. Did I miss something? Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, DynamoDB should delete expired items even if they were created before the TTL column was chosen. At least, nothing in the documentation suggests otherwise. [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/howitworks-ttl.html) explains how TTL works:

> DynamoDB compares the current time, in epoch time format, to the value stored in the user-defined Number attribute of an item. If the attribute’s value is in the epoch time format, is less than the current time, and is not older than 5 years, the item is deleted. Processing takes place automatically, in the background.

You said that you waited for 24 hours for the deletion to happen. Maybe this wasn't enough, because the same document also says:

> DynamoDB typically deletes expired items within 48 hours of expiration. The exact duration within which an item truly gets deleted after expiration is specific to the nature of the workload and the size of the table.

Now that 48 hours *have* passed, can you please check again?

**Update (based on the discussion above):**
If the TTL feature appears not to be working for, you should make sure that you are setting the TTL attribute correctly. First make sure you are setting the attribute with the correct name (this was the questioner's first problem). Then, you should make sure to set an **integer** values in this attribute (it can't be a string!). Finally make sure that this integer is the number of seconds since the epoch (midnight GMT, Jan 1, 1970) - the questioner accidentally used milliseconds instead of seconds here, so it didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Nadav.  I've just checked the table and the items are still there.  FYI there are only around 200 items in the table, so it's not huge.  Also, here are a couple of timestamps that are in the table: 15222051082, 15222051082.  The expiry attribute is definitely set as the TTL column since the name in the Items tab is set to "expiry (TTL)".

Comment: Oh... I suspect there still is a configuration problem, and it's not that the TTL doesn't apply to pre-existing data. Even in the announcement of the TTL feature (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-manage-dynamodb-items-using-time-to-live-ttl/) they talked about "purging" data (i.e., removing existing data), and about "a new or an existing table". Please try to insert new data with a TTL 10 seconds in the future. If this data also doesn't get removed, you'll know you have a configuration problem and it's not an issue of the pre-existing data.

Comment: Another wild guess here: The TTL field needs to be a number type. It can't be a string! If you have a string there, it will just be ignored and the item will never be expired. Could this be your problem?

Comment: Hmm, one last guess: Are you sure the TTL you gave me 15222051082, isn't a typo? It has one digits too many. According to my calculation, it's a date in the year 2452... Please check again where you got this number. Try this yourself here, for example: https://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: Nadav, The TTL did indeed have a typo (I pasted the wrong attribute value, sorry).  The actual TTL value is 1582857923396.  The field is indeed a number type.  I will try your suggestion about inserting a new item with a known-good value for the TTL attribute and let you know how it works.

Comment: I believe the TTL should be in seconds, did you use milliseconds?

Comment: Yes, I verified that 1582857923396 is indeed in milliseconds. Just remove the last three digits - 1582857923. That would be February 28th. It should be in seconds, not milliseconds. See example in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/howitworks-ttl.html.

Comment: Thank you so much Nadev.  You really helped me out on this.